# Haskell Snap: Executing an IO action within a handler?

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

Say, I have a random DB function in my separate DB.hs file.
Something like this:

```
savePerson :: Person -> IO ()
  savePerson p = do
  c <- connect
  run c "INSERT INTO persons (name, age) \
        \VALUES (?, ?)"
        [toSql (personName p), toSql (personAge p)]
  commit c
  disconnect c
  return ()
```

Now, how do I execute this functions within my handler in Site.hs if I import my DB.hs?

If I simply stick it in my handler like this(this is just an example):

```
insertPerson = do
  par <- getPostParams
  let p = toPerson par
  savePerson p
  return ()
  where
    toPerson m =
      Person {personName = head (m ! (B.pack "name"))
             ,personAge  = read (B.unpack (head (m ! (B.pack "age")))) :: Int
             }
```

This does not work. I dont want the handler to return anything, I just want it to save the Person and not return/render anything.

What is the correct way of doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `liftIO` since it is an instance of `MonadIO`.

Comment: So what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that you do not understand what the unit type and value are about.

The unit type is a special built-in type called "()", which has exactly one value, also called "()".

So for instance I can create a list of 4 units, which is of type "list of units".

```
fourUnits :: [()]
fourUnits = [(), (), (), ()]
```

The unit type is used where we don't want to have any other information.  So technically the type "IO ()" is the type of an IO action that gives the unit value.

A "do" clause unsugars to a chain of ">>=" invocations.  ">>=" has the type

```
(>>=) :: (Monad m) => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

In other words, the type of a "do" clause is the type returned by its last action.

So where you say

```
savePerson p
return ()
```

the "return ()" is spurious because it has exactly the same type as "savePerson p".

Remember that "return" has nothing to do with flow of control: it is merely a function with the type

```
return :: (Monad m) => a -> m a
```

It would have been better called "wrap" or "inject" or something similar to avoid this confusion.

Comment: You're right that the `return ()` is superfluous, but other than that, I don't think this has much to do with his question. As I understood it, his problem was that `savePerson p :: IO ()` but `insertPerson :: Snap ()` (though this was not really made clear since he omitted the type signature). @qubital's comment about using `liftIO` to lift `saveperson p` into the `Snap` monad was all he needed.

Comment: @Paul I thought the return just wraps the value in whatever monad you are currently in? I did not think that savePerson and return () would be the same. How can this be? savePerson returns an IO() Since all this is happening in the handler monad the last return just wraps the unit into the default handler context. I cant escape from a handler monad with an IO action, can I? Thank you very much for the explanation but I think my confusion was more about the return of the handler function and handler data type. liftIO did the trick. This is all that needed,

Comment: @bitbucket Thanks for understanding. You exactly pinpointed the source of my confusion and the reason for the question. My problem was the handler return type. I did not realize that Snap monad was stacked on IO. So I did not know how to execute a general IO action from within a handler. Can you please explain why return() is superfluous?

Comment: @r.sendecky The final statement in a `do` block provides the overall value for the entire block. The type of `return ()` in your example is `Snap ()`, but the type of the statement before it, `liftIO $ savePerson p` is also `Snap ()`. Since `return ()` has no additional effects other than to wrap a pure `()` value in the monad, and its type is exactly the same as the preceding statement, you can just omit the `return ()` entirely and the end result will be the same.